# How to load or save Doctrine associated entity into Zend_Auth session

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-auth

I am looking for some good solutions for a problem.

I am usig Doctrine 2.1 integrated to Zend Framework. I am using Zend_Auth with Zend_Auth_Storage_Session where I have stored User's entity. But entity of User is associtad to other Entity => AclRole. Each User has one AclRole.

For the first time, when I load user throught EntityManager, the AclRole is loaded as soon as call it in User. But when other page is loaded and entity of User is loaded from session, her 'locale' attribute is NULL.

Is there any good solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

I have an excellent solution, that i am using in my project, i will send you the github link when i've checked in my code today ;)